# R reading HDF5 data from a specific subset

Tags: r, subset, hdf5

At this point i am working on a project where i have to use large HDF5 files in R. I have a HDF5 file which consists of 4 subsets. the structure is as followed:

```
MeansSIS.HDF5

Quality (32-bit floating-point,735 x 1980)
TOA (32-bit floating-point,735 x 1980)
Energy (32-bit floating-point, 5 x 7 x 735 x 1980)
Transmissivity (32-bit floating-point,5 x 7 x 735 x 1980)
```

In my case i am interested in the subset "Energy".

So far i've used R 3.0.2 with the package `rhdf5`. I am able to read the entire subset by using the command:

```
IE<-h5read("meansSIS.HDF5", "Energy")
```

However the Energy subset is build so that each location from the 735x1980 has 5x7 inputs. I only need the 1,1 (the number in the first row, first column) input from these 5x7.

could someone please explain me how i can only substract this one number out of the smaller matrix for each pixel? I've tried several ways of naming it in the h5read command but unsuccesfully. Besides that am i completly new to hdf5 files and fairly new to R.

Thanks in advance for any tips or ideas!

Comment: Have you tried `IE[1,1]` ?

Comment: Yes, i've both set that column and row before assigning it to IE and then it gives an error: Object IE not found. And if i ask for it after reading in the hdf5 file with the line used before it will give the message: "incorrect number of dimensions"